# Quarkus: How to run StartupEvent only for non-PROD profiles?

Tags: quarkus

```java
@Singleton
public class Startup {
    private static final String ADMIN_ROLES = String.join(",", Api.adminuser.role, Api.apiuser.role);

    @Inject
    UserRepo repo;
    @Transactional
    public void loadUsersForTest(@Observes StartupEvent evt) {//TODO Need to load only for non-PROD profiles
        repo.deleteAll();// reset and load all test users
        repo.addTestUserOnly(Api.adminuser.testuser, Api.adminuser.testpassword, ADMIN_ROLES);
        repo.addTestUserOnly(Api.apiuser.testuser, Api.apiuser.testpassword, Api.apiuser.role);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a coupld of ways you can do this.

The first is to use `io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ProfileManage` like so:

```
@Singleton
public class Startup {
    private static final String ADMIN_ROLES = String.join(",", Api.adminuser.role, Api.apiuser.role);

    @Inject
    UserRepo repo;
    @Transactional
    public void loadUsersForTest(@Observes StartupEvent evt) {
        if ("prod".equals(io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ProfileManager.getActiveProfile())) { 
           return; 
        }
        repo.deleteAll();// reset and load all test users
        repo.addTestUserOnly(Api.adminuser.testuser, Api.adminuser.testpassword, ADMIN_ROLES);
        repo.addTestUserOnly(Api.apiuser.testuser, Api.apiuser.testpassword, Api.apiuser.role);
    }
}
```

The second is to use `io.quarkus.arc.profile.UnlessBuildProfile` like so:

```
@UnlessBuildProfile("prod")
@Singleton
public class Startup {
    private static final String ADMIN_ROLES = String.join(",", Api.adminuser.role, Api.apiuser.role);

    @Inject
    UserRepo repo;
    @Transactional
    public void loadUsersForTest(@Observes StartupEvent evt) {
        repo.deleteAll();// reset and load all test users
        repo.addTestUserOnly(Api.adminuser.testuser, Api.adminuser.testpassword, ADMIN_ROLES);
        repo.addTestUserOnly(Api.apiuser.testuser, Api.apiuser.testpassword, Api.apiuser.role);
    }
}
```

The second way is better since it will result in `Startup` never becoming a CDI bean when you build the production application.

Comment: It should be noted that the second option (`@UnlessBuildProfile`) gets evaluated at build time (as the name implies). This means we would have to produce two artifacts if we need a version with the bean enable and one with it disabled.

Comment: To select a bean at runtime, uou wan use the tip documented here: https://www.loicmathieu.fr/wordpress/en/informatique/quarkus-tip-selectionner-un-bean-au-runtime/
Quarkus 2.5 will provide a simpler way to do this: https://quarkus.io/version/main/guides/cdi-reference#declaratively-choose-beans-that-can-be-obtained-by-programmatic-lookup